# Drupal7 template suggestions for node is not working

Tags: theming

I created a new content type named job. Now I want to use custom node template for this content type.

I created file name `node--job.tpl.php` and cleared the cache, but it doesn't pick that file, it is picking only `node.tpl.php` file.

Anybody have any idea about this?

Comment: This is D7 yeah?

Answer (score 1):

Your usage is right.Check your code in detail!

Comment: i already did this.. not  sucessfull

Answer (score 0):

The [theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) is very handy if it comes to find the right template names. After enabling you can just point and click on whathever you want the theme to find the right name.

After changing templates you have to clear your caches. Otherwise they are not picked up. Either go to `admin/config/development/performance` or use `drush cc all`.