# Node template suggestion stopped to work for new content types

Tags: nodes

I experience the simmilar issue as asked [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39480/drupal7-template-suggestions-for-node-is-not-working)

I already have several template suggestions that are working properly following structure:

node--type.tpl.php

But for newly added content types, it does not work, whatever i do. I cleared cache, recreated content type, checked spelling.

How can i track in devel or in other way what is source of this error ?

Comment: May be you are not using correct theme suggestion... You can see theme suggestions by doing dpm($variables) in hook_preprocess_page(&$variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the strange Caching issue, source of which is yet unknown to me. It may me somehow connected to APC caching, or to nodeaccess cache. I am not yet sure.

After nervous session of clearing different layers of cache, i somehow get it to work.